# Valid IP address but can't surf without rebooting

Tags: windows-xp, internet, connection

I periodically lose internet and router connection at home. When this happens, others are using the router just fine. I am connecting directly through a wired connection to a Belkin router. I can release and renew the IP (and the IP addresses change to 0.0.0.0 and to an IP in my router's range beginning with 192.168.2. as they should) but still can't surf, can't access the router interface. Cycling the router doesn't help, and again, others are able to access the router fine at this time. Only rebooting the computer resolves the issue, and everything is wonderful for a few hours- and then I lose connection again.
I have several ideas where to go from here, but I'd like to get some advice first.
(Using Windows XP SP3, hardwired connection)

**Update**

As stated in the originally, releasing and renewing doesn't solve the issue. However, I have an update. I can ping localhost and my router IP with no problem at all when the issue occurs. However, repairing the network connection does not help. I AM able to get back on by disabling and then re-enabling the network connection in XP. What does that tell us?

Comment: Wait for the problem to happen, then attach the output of 'ipconfig /all' to your question.

Comment: when the problem occurs next, look through your event viewer. See if you can spot any obvious failures in the application and system logs.

Answer (score 2):

Try ping your router ip address with "ping 192.168.2.1" command

If the ping packets go thru, your physical network connection is ok.  Check the DNS server address.  Compare that address with DNS find in other working computer.

If DNS is ok, check the route with "route -n" command, make sure the default gateway is correct and netmask is correct.

You can log all these info when the system is working and compare them to when it is not working.  From that, you can investigate more on what cause the failure.

You can see this issue if there is another system in the network with the same ip or mac address.   You should not see any same mac address problem unless you are in a environment with a lot testing boards or pre-production unconfigured systems.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested ideas above are a good start for troubleshooting. In the meantime, you may be able to re-establish the connection without restarting if you type `ipconfig -renew` into the command prompt. That will renew your DHCP lease and perhaps restart the connection successfully.

Answer (score 0):

When it next happens I'd suggest you try and ping (or traceroute, probably with tracert -d w.x.y.z under Windows) to an external site by name (www.google.com) and by IP (209.85.229.103).

I'd guess that if you can ping the router ok (and I assume access it's web interface on the local IP address) that it is some sort of routing or DNS issue.

If you can get out on a traceroute for the IP but the name lookup fails it's DNS.

If both fail then maybe some sort of routing.